# Sort Dictionary<> on value, lookup index from key

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a Dictionary<> which I want to sort based on value so I've done this by putting the dictionary into a List<> then using the .Sort method.

I've then added this back into a Dictionary<>.  Is it possible to lookup the new index/order by using the Dictionary key??

```
Dictionary<int, MyObject> toCompare = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();

toCompare.Add(0, new MyObject());
toCompare.Add(1, new MyObject());
toCompare.Add(2, new MyObject());

Dictionary<int, MyObject> items = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();
List<KeyValuePair<int, MyObject>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<int, MyObject>>   (toCompare);

// Sort.
values.Sort(new MyComparer());

// Convert back into a dictionary.
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, PropertyAppraisal> item in values)
{
      // Add to collection.
  items.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}

// THIS IS THE PART I CAN'T DO...
int sortedIndex = items.GetItemIndexByKey(0);
```

Comment: Isn't the ordering of a Dictionary undefined in the c# defenition?

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do? If you need a unique collection, use a dictionary. If you need the index of an item in a sorted list, use SortedList.

Comment: @Michael Todd: a `SortedList` is not the correct solution. He wants the items to be ordered according to a custom comparison on the *values* in the collection.

Comment: The problem is that I want a Dictionary for fast lookup, but now I want to sort it (somehow) using my custom comparison and lookup the index of any of the items using the Dictionary key.

Comment: @Dan Tao (Didn't get that, which is why I asked.) @paulio So, to borrow from database terminology, you want a table with both a primary key (to prevent dupes) and an index on the data (to quickly get to the data and/or _back_ to the primary key if needed)? If so, spoulson's solution should work (if you use your _values_ in the list, not your _keys_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your data in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, but use a `List<TKey>` to sort the keys, then iterate as such:

```
IDictionary<int, MyObject> dict = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();
// ... Populate dict with data.

IList<int> keyList = new List<int>();
keyList.AddRange(dict.Keys);

// Sort keyList based on key's value.
// MyObject must implement IComparable<MyObject>.
keyList.Sort(delegate(int x, int y) {
   return dict[x].CompareTo(dict[y]);
});

foreach (int key in keyList) {
   MyObject value = dict[key];
}
```

This way, your list is merely a sorted index and does not affect your storage algorithm.

Comment: Do you have a more involved example as I need to sort by value not by key.  Also, I'm on .net 2.0.

Comment: I'm still unsure how to lookup the index from keyList after the sort using my key?  I'm trying to avoid linear searches through the sorted key list.

Comment: The simplest approach to go from key to sorted index lookup, you'll need to pregenerate a `Dictionary<>` where its key is the key in question, and its value is the index in the sorted list.  `int idx = indexLookup[key]`.  This is ideal for large sets of data, where a linear search would not scale.  But it would not be ideal if the data changes frequently, requiring regeneration of the lookup dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Take this extension method:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Sort<TKey, TValue, TSortingKey>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source, 
    Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, TSortingKey> selector)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (var pair in source.OrderBy(selector))
        result.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    return result;
}
```

And usage:

```
    Dictionary<int, MyType> source = new Dictionary<int, MyType>();
    Dictionary<int, MyType> sortedDictionary = source.Sort(i => i.Value.Property1); //sort dictionary by values (by property "Property1" of type MyType
```

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately I'm stuck with .net 2.0